# How do I use IIS 6 Web Deploy to deploy to a non-default virtual path?

Tags: msbuild, iis-6, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm using IIS6, Web Deploy Agent Service, and MSBuild's MSDeploy hooks to deploy.  It deploys right now with this set of arguments to MSBuild:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:MSDeployServiceURL=example.com
/p:DeployIISAppPath=example.com/DeploySiteName
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/p:MsDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificated=True
/p:UserName=login
/p:Password=pw
```

With that, it will deploy to `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\example.com80`, where the Website files are located.

Unfortunately, I need it to deploy to `D:\Webs`, mostly for space reasons.

I'm trying to figure out what switch, if any, will allow me to deploy to an alternate physical path and map the virtual directory.

I tried reverse-engineering `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` like another SO post suggested, but I failed... I tried using combinations of these parameters and they had no visible effect:

```
/p:DeployIisAppPhysicalPath=D:\Webs
/p:RemoteSitePhysicalPath=D:\Webs
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a virtual folder in IIS6 to point to a different physical location to start with, then pass in the path and parameters like you listed above MSDeploy will write to the correct physical location.